# Issue with retrieving last row record from the SQL Database

Tags: sql, database, row, record

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomID FROM RoomQuantity A WHERE A.RoomID = (SELECT MAX(RoomID) FROM RoomQuantity)";

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 RoomID FROM RoomQuantity ORDER BY RoomID desc;";
```

Database
Table : RoomQuantity
- Column : RoomID
- Data in RoomID :
R1
R2
R3
R4
R5
R6
R7
R8
R9
R10

Problem - Always retrieved R9 instead of R10

Comment: Post the code that reads the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If RoomID is not a numeric data type (as I would assume, as the data is "R1"), then an alphanumeric sort is used.

R9 > R1
and 
R9 > R10

as only the beginning of the strings is compared (here: 2 characters).

Answer (score 1):

The sort order of a *string* would be R1 -> R10 -> R2. What did you expect?

If you want a number sort, then you'll need this

```
SELECT TOP 1 RoomID
FROM RoomQuantity
ORDER BY
      CAST(REPLACE(RoomID, 'R', '') AS int) DESC
```

Don't expect great performance if you gave a lot of rows because an index on RoomID will be ignored

Other options:

- Pad numbers (as per Ralph Shillington's answer)
- Store the number as int and add the 'R' at display time (or as computed column)
- Use my CAST/REPLACE as a computed, indexed column in the table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select RoomID  from RoomQuantity order by RoomID  desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu'll have to zero pad your data if you're hoping to retrieve characters likes their are numbers.
R01 R02 R03 R04 R05 ... R10 would give you the result you're looking for.  However now that you're down that road, you may conclude that your data model should be rethought.